# I keep getting a syntax error when I try to check for int values in a substring?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, error-handling, syntax

For a homework assigntment I have to check for int values in a VARCHAR for example:
I have values that look like this:

```
cityCode
Cott1254
Stam2512
Berl0102
```

I want to be able to check the sum of int values in these tables and make sure that they are even numbers > 0

I have tried the following but im getting a syntax error and this is only for checking if the whole number is greater than 0. The main problem is resolving the syntax error that I get.

```
CHECK SUBSTR(CAST(accommodatiecode, 5,4) AS INT)> 0;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL (historically) does not implement check constraints.  But the correct syntax is:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_col
    check (SUBSTR(accommodatiecode, 5, 4) + 0) > 0);
```

This, of course, does not check for even or odd.  That would be more like:

```
accomodatiecode regexp '[0-9]{4}[02468]$'
```

Comment: MySQL did implement CHECK constraint in 8.0.16